# searching for doubles with regular expressions

Tags: python, regex

Is there a regular expression which would match floating point numbers but not if this is a part of a construct like 15.01.2016?

`re.match(rex, s)` should be successful if `s` would be

```
1.0A
1.B
.1
```

and not successful for `s` like

```
1.0.0
1.0.1
20.20.20.30
12345.657.345
```

**Edit:** 
The crucial part is the combination of the constrains: `"[0-9]*\.[0-9]*"` and not part of `"[0-9]+\.[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)+"`

Comment: I can match doubles and something like xxx.xxx.xxx the combination of both constrains is the problem

Comment: Could you show your regex expression for that?

Comment: To answer the question you actually asked: *Yes, there is*. But I second Anton’s comment. You may wish to refer to the help files, particularly [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Also, check the docs for lookahead assertions.

Comment: You can use `\d` instead of `[0-9]`

Comment: @Anton Protopopov I updated the question with my regexes and narrowed the scope of the question to the crutial part

Comment: `Sentence 1.2nd Sentence.`

Comment: Somebody is just duplicate crazy here.. This is not a normal float match.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this regex based on look arounds in python:

```
(?<![\d.])(?:\d*\.\d+|\d+\.\d*)(?![\d.])
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/iR7fC8/1)

- `(?![\d.])` is lookahead assertion to fail the match if next char is DOT or digit
- `(?<![\d.])` is lookbehind assertion to fail the match if previous char is DOT or digit

Answer (score 2):

The following solution uses also lookahead and lookbehind as anubhava mentioned. Additionally it takes care of negative numbers, the powers of ten (also negative ones) and integers (witout a .):

```
(?<![\d.])-?(?:\d+\.?\d*|\d*\.\d+)([eE]-?\d+)?(?![.\d])
```

If you add some additional characters in the lookabehind `(?<![\d.])` you can avoid matches in a random bunch of characters or at the end of a word (e.g. if you want no match for `"python3"` ).